# Nginx default server showing incorrectly for site homepage only

Tags: caching, proxy, nginx, centos, reverse-proxy

I have a rather strange issue that appears to have only started in the last few days (no changes have been made in the last few days) . I'll try and describe it as best I can but please let me know if I need to post particular configs etc.

I have a setup with an nginx load balancer in front of 2 backend nginx web servers running on CentOS 6.3. This site has been running fine up until now but recently when visiting the home page it has been showing me the page I created as the default site on the webserver (it is a discrete notice that says the host header has not been recognised on the webserver). When you visit a sub-page e.g. domain.com/about-us it is fine but visiting domain.com shows the default site. It appears that this problem can be solved by disabling the caching on the load balancer for this particular site. As soon as the cache is not used, the homepage shows correctly.

The cache on the load balancer is held in a RAM drive mapped to /cache with a total available size of 256Mb. The cache configuration is as follows

```
proxy_cache_path /cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=app-cache:30m max_size=126m inactive=10m;
proxy_temp_path /cache/tmp;
proxy_buffer_size 8192;
proxy_max_temp_file_size 1m;
```

I reduced the total size of the cache last night as I have a feeling it was causing another problem I saw recently where we came under extreme load, the cache filled to the max allowed size of 256Mb but that left no room on the mount point for the temp path to buffer files from the upstreams and started serving empty files to clients.

I've looked in the error log for the particular site and found a number of instances of

```
2013/01/03 05:47:24 [crit] 22889#0: *352983 pwrite() "/cache/tmp/0000028264" failed (28: No space left on device) while reading upstream, client: 121.58.173.7, server: www.domain.com, request: "GET /images/slider-plus.gif HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.100.193:80/images/slider-plus.gif", host: "www.domain.com", referrer: "http://www.domain.com/example-page"
```

A df -h shows the /cache mount to only be using 1% of the available space at the moment, so I'm not sure why I should be still getting this error.

The nginx version on the load balancer is 1.0.11 (built from source)
The nginx version on the web server is 1.0.15 (installed from package from epel)

I realise that nginx is in need of updating, I only realised this yesterday. If this is the problem then I can bring forward the plans to update it, but it'd be useful to have confirmation of what this problem might be and how it can be solved.

Please feel free to request any extra info needed to help diagnose this situation.

Many thanks

Eric

Edit: I thought I should add that the problem of the site not showing the homepage does present itself when the server is under very little load, the load balancer is idle most of the time with not much traffic. The empty file problem was only shown when the servers were under much higher load than usual.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `free -m` and `df -h /cache`?

Comment: [dh -h screen shot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/816359/df.png) sorry couldn't get the output to format in a readable manner in a comment. Let me know if there is some other way I should do this. Thanks

Comment: You can add extra detail in your original post or in a [pastebin](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pastebin)

Comment: Are these hosts virtual machines? You may be hitting a limit on the hypervisor. Please give the output of `ulimit -a` and let us know what vm technology is in use (if applicable)

Comment: [df -h and free -m pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tPyYKyQN)

Comment: Yes, the hosts are virtual machines run on VMWare. [Pastebin of ulimit -a](http://pastebin.com/hpyG3wDx)

Comment: Perhaps you've run out of inodes. `df -Ti /cache`

Comment: That command shows a high number for free [Pastebin for df -Ti /cache](http://pastebin.com/6wgtguC9) . The puzzling part is that the page that is loaded is from the webserver default site, so unless that has come from the /cache folder it would appear that the host header wasn't properly passed to the web server? The homepage would also have Google Analytics cookies attached to it so it shouldn't be cached anyway. I haven't been able to find an instance of a strange host header appearing in the web server default log file though.

Comment: I think we need to see some more of your nginx configurations (both reverse proxy and web server) to be able to help you more

Comment: [Load balancer nginx configs](http://pastebin.com/7N1CVxWs) [Site virtual host load balancer](http://pastebin.com/qYPcV7Q2) [Web server nginx config](http://pastebin.com/gWAiT1du) [Default server .conf](http://pastebin.com/H1WsDiwu) [Site virtual host config web server](http://pastebin.com/AYy6DB0s)

Comment: I've trawled through your config without much luck. The only strange thing I can see is that `proxy_cache_path` is used a bit differently from the nginx docs, I would expect it to look more like `proxy_cache_path /cache/app-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=app-cache:30m max_size=126m inactive=10m;` -- but I'm clearly out of my depth now :)

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts much appreciated :) I'll change the cache directory in the `proxy_cache_path` directive to a sub-directory to clean that up. I assumed in the docs the reason they have a sub directory is that they have 3 different caches set up. I don't fully understand the 1:2 part of the cache setting either or how this should be determined? I haven't been able to find an explanation of this.

Comment: I think the key_zone has to match the subdirectory name as well, though I don't understand why. Near as I can tell, the levels parameter sets the depth of the cache subdirectories and the number of subdirectories at each level. 1:2 will use the last character for the first level (up to 16 subdirectories) and the previous two characters for the second level (up to 256 subdirectories).

Comment: I've changed the directory the cache goes to to match the key_zone name. That's about as much as I could gather from the levels description too. It doesn't really explain why you'd choose one configuration over another though.

Comment: I can take a guess. File systems tend to slow down on big directories, if you have more levels of indirection you get many smaller directories.